# Webbrowser control and security alert messages

Tags: c#, security, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I met some problem and need help of the community.

I'm developing simple winform application and use webbrowser control to navigate between web sites. My desktop OS is Windows XP and IE6 as default browser.

Problem is in next case. When I try navigate using my browser from website to another one using HTTPS connection and then going back IE6 show security alert message box with message than I'm trying use non secure connection. This messagebox is blocking page loading and ask user to click OK button to continue loading.

My webbrowser control doesn't show this security alert and doesn't load next page. It's important bug in my application.

How this security alert could be shown in the webbrowser control? how I could accept to this messagebox from c# to continue page loading without showing security alert?

Comment: I'm new in window messages and other interops if they needs.

Answer (score 1):

Windows XP SP2 provides the WarnOnHTTPSToHTTPRedirect Value Name, at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings 
I am not sure if you can override it using your own implementation of  IDocHostUIHandler2::GetOverrideKeyPath. I don't remember it is probed under my overriden registry key Last time I run my customized webbrowser app.